How to import aggregated (i.e. cradle-to-gate) at the LCIA score level?
I would like to import aggregated LCIA scores to be part of my inventory with Brightway 2.5.
I used to rely on https://pypi.org/project/bw2agg/ in BW2.
This package would add - for example - an impact score of 0.00140 kg P-Eq Unit('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13', 'freshwater eutrophication', 'FEP') as a biosphere flow and let you integrate in your broader inventory.
Is there an equivalent or an approach that work in 2.5?

I noticed a while ago that Chris created this repo https://github.com/brightway-lca/bw_aggregation
I'm unsure if it's fully developed yet, but it might be good to check it out.
